# How to use mouseclick to change a variable using OpenCV and Python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm a noobie at programming and this question may sound easy and dumb but I really can not do it! The goal here is to change the color between green, blue and red everytime I click. I'm sorry if that's obvious, but I'm for hours stuck at this. That's the code I have, that prints everytime the same color. Now, I want to add something to change colors everytime I click.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),100,color=(0,255,0),thickness=10)

cv2.namedWindow(winname='my_drawing')

cv2.setMouseCallback('my_drawing', draw_circle)

img = np.zeros((512,512,3),np.int8)

while True:

    cv2.imshow('my_drawing', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) &0xFF == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

I've tried a lot of stuff that I don't even know where to start, but I've tried creating a variable inside the function that each time it enters on the function, it sums, and depending on the value(using if) it goes to a different color, but the variable doesn't seem to change if it enters the loop again, then I've tried returning the variable as well. No success. Adding a Paramater. No Success as well. I believe it's such a simple thing that my head cannot think at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way... make a list of the colours you want to cycle through. Have a global variable that you use as the index into the list to get the next colour. Each time you use it, add 1 to it and reduce it modulo the length of the list of colours. Colour the circle with value from the colour list as indexed by the index.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

index = 0
colours = [[255,0,0], [0,255,0], [0,0,255]]

def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global index
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),100,color=colours[index],thickness=10)
        index = (index+1) % len(colours)

cv2.namedWindow(winname='my_drawing')

cv2.setMouseCallback('my_drawing', draw_circle)

img = np.zeros((512,512,3),np.int8)

while True:

    cv2.imshow('my_drawing', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) &0xFF == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

[image]